# I don't know how but I managed to create a database named exactly "*" in mongodb and I cannot delete it

Tags: mongodb, database

I really don't know why but while I was trying to do some mongodump I began to see a `*` table. So I cannot make mongodump to work because it will try to save the `*` database which will imply and incorrect filename..

Anyway, I cannot delete, from cmd line:

```
    > show dbs
    *       (empty)
    __applicationManager    0.03125GB
    __sessions      0.03125GB
    admin   (empty)
    local   (empty)
    migration       0.03125GB
    > use *
    ... // enter once
    ... // enter again and happens the following
    error2:invalid string position
    > use admin
    switched to db admin
    > use *
    ... db.dropDatabase()
    Mon Nov 12 10:50:45 SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (shellhelp2):1
    > show dbs
    *       (empty)
    __applicationManager    0.03125GB
    __sessions      0.03125GB
    admin   (empty)
    local   (empty)
    migration       0.03125GB
```

Tried the comment:

```
> db.getCollection("*").drop()
false
> show dbs
*       (empty)
__applicationManager    0.03125GB
__sessions      0.03125GB
admin   (empty)
local   (empty)
migration       0.03125GB
test    (empty)
```

Comment: `db.getCollection("*").drop()` should be able to remove regardless is special characters.

Comment: Which version of MongoDB? There is a [bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4229) that `mongdump` creates a DB named "\*", but I am not sure how that affects the database system. I think that "\*" is a system database.

Comment: mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.0, so should I drop or not much?

Comment: @Sammaye: it doesn't work :S

Comment: @Totty according to the bug report that the fix was not made for `2.0`, but for later versions. I advise updating your mongoDB, if possible. If the database does not appear to use up disk space (check mongo's data files), then I think you can safely ignore it.

Comment: I cannot because it is not supported by win xp... Any other way to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

You can always remove it from the Windows explorer:

- Shut down mongodb
- Find the database files on disk - there will be a bunch of them starting with * then a . and then a number (or "ns"). Remove all of those - make sure not to delete things that you don't want to remove, unless you have a backup of course.
- Start up mongodb again.

Comment: There is not what? The database files must exist somewhere.

Comment: my folder does not contain a file for each database shown using the command: "show dbs". I double checked the folder.

Comment: Uh? What is your MongoDB data dir, and which files are in there?

Comment: I run mongod like this: mongod.exe --port 9000 --dbpath="..\..\..\..\db" --nojournal, and in the "db" folder there is not the * database aswell as others I've drop. But they still show up in the "show dbs" command and in UMongo. I think UMongo don't drop properly the databases as they remain there somehow even if there are no files. Maybe mongod saves the databases metadata somewhere else...